# How to test code that works with Docker?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, docker

We have some Java code that works with Docker. For example, one method may create docker network, create a container or two, set the labels, tags, expose some ports etc.

We want to test this, but our unit tests became integration tests, since every test is actually working with real Docker. The major issue with that is the speed of the tests - which we have many - it is horrible slow for developers. And when test is running, the machine is almost frozen.

We do have a layer on top of Docker, plus we use docker java library to talk to the API.

Question: how we should design our tests in this case?

Current idea is to have 'mockup' docker client, that receives commands, but do not issue them on the real docker; and then we can check if commands are set correctly. For this we would also need to simulate docker behavior, like calling `docker ps` and so on. Moreover, we can't be 100% sure that command we sent is *really* working with Docker! Imagine if docker version is changed, and something in API was changed - how we would be able to detect this?

Comment: If the bottleneck is the container _creation_ (the rest sounds fast), a simple fix would be to create dummy containers rather than running all the default commands they consist of. (also you can check potential speedups by using an alternative [storage driver](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Docker#Storage_driver)

Comment: nah, its not just the creation. it is a several things we do and set on one or more containers... we already run 'tiny' containers.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're already on the path, just general suggestions:

- minimize the working set, sounds like you're already doing this with micro containers
- Minimize integration resources, if you're using an N node network, would N-1 suffice? What is the absolute minimum number of resources necessary to verify the target functionality. (0, 1, and 2 instances)
- what are the minimum essential components of the docker API you need to protect against?  Will `docker ps` change? Do you even need to care about `docker ps`?
- Aggregate expensive tests when possible, If a network is created for every single test, is there anyway to create a single network for a group of tests? Or to overload a single test with multiple assertions? These are all tradeoffs, by overloading a single test failure will mask later assertions?
- Prune duplicate, or overlapping tests

Unfortunately, there may be some leaps of faith to speed up the test suite.  If there isn't any blatant duplication, moving things to a fake docker implementation is no where near as strong assertions as testing against actual docker.